# How to convert PDF to low-resolution (but good quality) JPEG?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript

When I use the following ghostscript command to generate jpg thumbnails from PDFs, the image quality is often very poor:

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=jpeggray -g465x600 -dUseCropBox -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=pdf_to_lowres.jpg test.pdf
```

By contrast, if I use ghostscript to generate a high-resolution png, and then use mogrify to convert the high-res png to a low-res jpg, I get pretty good results.

```
gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pnggray -g2550x3300 -dUseCropBox -dPDFFitPage -sOutputFile=pdf_to_highres.png test.pdf
mogrify -thumbnail 465x600 -format jpg -write pdf_to_highres_to_lowres.jpg pdf_to_highres.png
```

Is there any way to achieve good results while bypassing the intermediate pdf -> high-res png step? I need to do this for a large number of pdfs, so I'm trying to minimize the compute time.

Here are links to the images referenced above:

1. [test.pdf](http://partifi.org/stackoverflow/test.pdf)
2. [pdf_to_lowres.jpg](http://partifi.org/stackoverflow/pdf_to_lowres.jpg)
3. [pdf_to_highres.png](http://partifi.org/stackoverflow/pdf_to_highres.png)
4. [pdf_to_highres_to_lowres.jpg](http://partifi.org/stackoverflow/pdf_to_highres_to_lowres.jpg)

Comment: Have a look at [this helpful answer](https://serverfault.com/a/797110/168205), it might fix your issue without using Ghostscript at all. It did for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option that seems to improve the output a lot: `-dDOINTERPOLATE`. Here's what I got by running the same command as you but with the `-dDOINTERPOLATE` option:

[image: JPEG with -dDOINTERPOLATE]

I'm not sure what [interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) method this uses but it seems pretty good, especially in comparison to the results without it.

P.S. Consider outputting PNG images (`-sDEVICE=pnggray`) instead of JPEG. For most PDF documents (which tend to have just a few solid colors) it's a [more appropriate](http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/jpeg-vs-png-image-quality-or-bandwidth/5385/) choice.

Comment: +1 for "Consider outputting PNG images", there are no silver bullets in image compression, and jpeg is not a good choice for images with text or high contrast figures in general.

Comment: If I could I'd vote 100 times this answer!! After days and days, -dDOINTERPOLATE has been the solution

Answer (score 3):

Your PDF looks like it is just a wrapper around a jpeg already.

Try using the pdfimages program from xpdf to extract the actual image rather than rendering 
to a file.

Comment: That might work for this particular test file, but I'm hoping for a more robust solution that works even if the PDF is not wrapping a single image.